# editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath called three time at the same time. Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I've a TableView with two UILabel for each row.
When the user swipe on a cell, I would like to reduce the frame of first label on my cell, in order to fix this problem:

[image: bug_image]

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:NO] autorelease];
    }

    custom_cell = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 200, 45)] autorelease];


    custom_cell.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    custom_cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [custom_cell setText:[[self.Notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]objectForKey:@"Text"]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:custom_cell];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat: @"dd MMM yy"];

    [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSDate *dateTmp = [[self.Notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CDate"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate: dateTmp];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    [dateFormat release];

    return cell;


}
```

Then, in order to reduce the frame of first label on my cell, I've written this code:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"row=%d", indexPath.row);

    custom_cell.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 150, 45);

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

The result is partially correct. The last label of my tableView is always reduced, not the right one.

Also the console print three times the NSLog message. Why?

```
2012-06-13 22:07:34.809 myVoyager[1935:16103] row=0
2012-06-13 22:07:34.810 myVoyager[1935:16103] row=0
2012-06-13 22:07:34.813 myVoyager[1935:16103] row=0
```

Thanks,
Alessandro from Pisa (sorry for my english!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm Valerio from Pisa! 
You should do like this in your editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
UITableViewCell *myCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and then set the frame to the cell.

Comment: Hi Valerio, thank you for your help. I've the same problem.
The method `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` is called three times at the same time as you can see on my previous console message. So, I reduce the frame for three times in succession. I do not expect this. Why? I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: First things I see: You need to use the cell identifier when you alloc the cell, otherwise is pointless to get a reused cell from the stack with "dequeue" method. Then use an instance variable for your dateformatter and set it up once because it requires memory and computation, not suitable in each cell. For the repeating problem, how many sections and rows do you have in your table?